# Google Chrome OS ISO

Tags: google-chrome-os

First of all, a few questions as I'm a bit confused :P

Is the Chrome OS that is shipped on Chromebooks "Chromium"?

I'm wanting to buy a Chromebook, but I want to download an ISO or other similar format first so I can try it out in VMware.

To be clear, I'm wanting the *exact* version that ships on Chromebooks, as I want to get a good feel for what I'll be buying

Where can I find this? I've found other things but I'm not sure they're the actual Chrome OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome OS is not Chromium OS. Check this:

http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-run-chrome-os-not-chromium-os-on.html

Comment: So, why not mark your question answered? :)

Comment: Done. For others reading this, I was unsure as well at first; Chromium is not Chrome OS. If you're looking to test out what you'll get on a Chromebook, follow this link ^

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Chrome OS in virtual box as shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/128087/how-to-run-chrome-os-in-virtualbox-and-try-out-chrome-os-before-buying-a-chromebook/). Virtualbox builds are available [here](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)

Chromium is just the chrome browser (more or less). Chrome OS might use chromium for its browser, but its more complicated.

Comment: Just to be sure, those are the exact builds that come shipped with a Chromebook?

Comment: These are daily builds, so likely a bit more unstable, but ya these are what would become the OS on the chromebooks.

Comment: Here is a step by step tutorial I did for 'testing' ChromiumOS in Virtualbox - http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/ it will be very similar to what you will find in chromebook that you will buy... depend on the iso you are using.